# What is equal to focus(), select() in jquery to angular 4

Tags: angular

How to focus on a specific element after saving a record in angular 4?
In JQuery there is focus() and select(). What is similar to this in angular?

Comment: `.nativeElement.focus();`

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using vanilla javascript or jquery in Angular apps, the only thing that may interact with your DOM is Angular.

Look at angular `@HostListener()` to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
   <div>
     <input #toFocus type="text" name="name" />
   </div>
   <button (click)="save()">click</button>
  `})

export class App {
 @ViewChild ('toFocus ') tofocus;

 save() {
   this.tofocus.nativeElement.focus();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a directive to achieve the "focus". from [spirosikmd](https://github.com/spirosikmd/angular2-focus/blob/master/src/focus.directive.ts)

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[focus]'
})
export class FocusDirective {
  @Input() focus: boolean;
  private element: HTMLElement;

  constructor($element: ElementRef) {
    this.element = $element.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.giveFocus();
  }

  giveFocus() {
    if (this.focus) {
      this.element.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

In order to work you must have a input like

```
<input id="inputD" [focus]="condicion">
```

In your .ts, you make condicion=true

Answer (score -1):

```
let inputField: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>document.querySelectorAll('.className')[0];
   inputField && inputField.focus();
```